# I want to authorize through vk.com with using python-social-auth and get error with redirect uri

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, vk

#### Error

```
{
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"redirect_uri is incorrect, check application redirect uri in the settings page"
}
```

#### settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.vk.VKOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_KEY = '****'
SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_SECRET = '*****'
```

On vk.com `http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/vk-oauth2` as redirect URI

Comment: try to use http://localhost:8000/complete/vk-oauth2  as redirect URI and open your browser to open http://localhost:8000 and then try to login .

Comment: i tried, it didn't help

Comment: Sorry,  but redirect uri errors usually caused by mismatching of requested uri or callback uri(redirect uri).

Comment: Make shure that redirect_uri reali is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/vk-oauth2', you need to view the network requests in the browser (use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?utm_source=dcc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see network request and in it was param `redirect_uri`:

http://localhost:8000/complete/vk-oauth2/.

I paste it in redirect uri on vk.com. And authorizing is ended successfully.
To see request press f12 and go to tab network (in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

"social_auth" builds the complete URL via Django, it looks at X_FORWARDED_FOR header. If you have installed locally Nginx, config near will help you:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.loc;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```